# How to push a big file data in talend?

Tags: talend

I have created a table where I have a text input file which is 7.5 GB in size and there are 65 million records and now I want to push that data into an Amazon RedShift table.

But after processing 5.6 million records it's no longer moving.

What can be the issue? Is there any limitation with tFileOutputDelimited as the job has been running for 3 hours.

Below is the job which I have created to push data in to Redshift table.

tFileInputDelimited(.text)---tMap--->tFilOutputDelimited(csv)

|

|

tS3Put(copy output file to S3) ------> tRedShiftRow(createTempTable)--> tRedShiftRow(COPY to Temp)

Comment: do you know what part the job is stuck..is it waiting at creating the flat file (csv) or rather has your flat file created? if yes, then has the file been uploaded to S3? ..it will be interesting to see what point your job is stuck..as redshift copy to temp table command would be fast and should not stuck..

Answer (score 0):

The limitation comes from Tmap component, its not the good choice to deal with large amount of data, for your case, you have to enable the option "Store temp data" to overcome the memory consumption limitation of Tmap.
Its well described in [Talend Help Center](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendPlatformforDataServicesStudioUserGuide54EN/9.2.6+Solving+memory+limitation+issues+in+tMap+use).

Comment: I dont think tMap is causing issue as there is no Join/lookup as per the above design. tMap becomes costly when we use to join two or more tables and data is huge then we will end-up in going with store temp data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, tFilOutputDelimited(csv) is creating the problem. Any file can't handle after certain amount of data. Not sure thought. Try to find out a way to load only portion of the parent input file and commit it in redshift. Repeat the process till your parent input file gets completely processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy command option to load large data into aws redshift, if the copy command doesn't support txt file, then we need to have csv file. processing 65 million records will create issue. so we need to perform split and run. for that create 65 iterations and do process 1 million data a a time . To implement this use tloop and set the values inside the component. take the global variables of tloop in header and limit values of tinputdelimited component

job:

```
tloop----->tinputfiledelimited---->tmap(if needed)--------> tfileoutdelimited
```

also enable the option "Store temp data" to handle the memory issue

Answer (score 0):

use **AWS Glue** to push your file data from S3 to Redshift. AWS Glue will easily push the large data into redshift without any issue.

Steps:

1: Create a connection with your Redshift

2: create a database and two tables.

```
   a: Data-from-S3 (this will use to crawl file data from S3)
   b: data-to-redshift ( add redshift connection)
```

3: Create a Job:

```
   a: In Data source, select the "Data-from-S3" table
   b: In Data Target, select the "data-to-redshift" table
```

4: Run the job.

Note: You can also automate this with lambda and SNS trigger.