# Talend- Memory issues. Working with big files

Tags: memory, split, talend

Before admins start to eating me alive, I would like to say to my defense that I cannot comment in the original publications, because I do not have the power, therefore, I have to ask about this again.

I have issues running a job in talend (**Open Studio for BIG DATA**!). I have an archive of 3 gb. I do not consider that this is too much since I have a computer that has 32 GB in RAM.

While trying to run my job, first I got an error related to **heap memory issue**, then it changed for a **garbage collector error**, **and now It doesn't even give me an error.** (just do nothing and then stops)

I found this SOLUTIONS and:

a)  [Talend performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960392/talend-performance)

**#Kailash commented that parallel is only on the condition that I have to be subscribed to one of the Talend Platform solutions**. My comment/question: So there is no other similar option to parallelize  a job with a 3Gb archive size?

b)  [Talend 10 GB input and lookup out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536042/talend-10-gb-input-and-lookup-out-of-memory-error)

**#54l3d mentioned that its an option to split the lookup file into manageable chunks (may be 500M), then perform the join in many stages for each chunk.** My comment/cry for help/question: how can I do that, I do not know how to split the look up, can someone explain this to me a little bit more graphical

c)  [How to push a big file data in talend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236819/how-to-push-a-big-file-data-in-talend)
just to mention that I also went through the "c" but I don't have any comment about it.

The job I am performing (thanks to #iMezouar) looks like this:

1) I have an inputFile MySQLInput coming from a DB in MySQL (3GB)

2) I used the tFirstRows to make it easier for the process (not working)

3) I used the tSplitRow to transform the data form many simmilar columns to only one column.

4) MySQLOutput

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvbeZ.jpg)

Thanks again for reading me and double  thanks for answering.

Comment: Hello again ;) could you please clarify this: 1) "I have an archive of 3 gb", reading on I understand your data comes from a MySQL table, so what is the archive you mention? 2) Is the job giving the error exactly like in the image you linked or that's another job?

Comment: 1) yeah my archive comes from a MySQL table :) 2) exactly is the job of the image that is giving me an error.

Comment: Yes I figured you meant MySQL data, calling it archive kinda threw me off :)
Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, your query returns a lot of data (3GB), and that is causing an error in your job. I suggest the following :
1. Filter data on the database side : replace `tSampleRow` by a `WHERE` clause in your `tMysqlInput` component in order to retrieve fewer rows in Talend.
2. MySQL jdbc driver by default retrieves all data into memory, so you need to use the `stream` option in `tMysqlInput`'s advanced settings in order to stream rows.

Comment: Incredible!! It work only with activating the `stream` option! You are the king of talend and a life savior!! Thank you very much (AGAIN!!)

Comment: I'm happy to help :) but I'm no king, when you work with Talend for a few years, you learn all these little tricks ;)